# How to install Pandas when PIP fails due to metadata generation error?

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am trying to install Pandas in a standalone installation of Python 3.12 and I keep getting an error saying "metadata-generation-failed."  I am able to install Pandas in my Anaconda installation but I need this one to be totally separate because I am using it to connect to VB.net.  I have updated PIP and the setup tools and I get the same error.  How can I get Pandas installed?

[image]

The install command and the output are as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python312-32\Scripts>pip install pandas
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.1.4.tar.gz (4.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\realt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ew6o36bq\pandas_25d69bcb06c84eb088749c1946920e14 C:\Users\realt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ew6o36bq\pandas_25d69bcb06c84eb088749c1946920e14\.mesonpy-swd4lt0x\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\realt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ew6o36bq\pandas_25d69bcb06c84eb088749c1946920e14\.mesonpy-swd4lt0x\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\realt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ew6o36bq\pandas_25d69bcb06c84eb088749c1946920e14
      Build dir: C:\Users\realt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ew6o36bq\pandas_25d69bcb06c84eb088749c1946920e14\.mesonpy-swd4lt0x\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.1.4
      Activating VS 17.8.3
      C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.38.33133 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33133 for x64")
      C linker for the host machine: link link 14.38.33133.0
      C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.38.33133 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33133 for x64")
      C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.38.33133.0
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.36)
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Program python found: YES (C:\Program Files (x86)\Python312-32\python.exe)
      Need python for x86_64, but found x86
      Run-time dependency python found: NO (tried sysconfig)

      ..\..\pandas\_libs\tslibs\meson.build:23:7: ERROR: Python dependency not found

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\realt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ew6o36bq\pandas_25d69bcb06c84eb088749c1946920e14\.mesonpy-swd4lt0x\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Can you paste the full output of the command you ran here as text?

Comment: Sure.  I will add it to the original question.  It is too long to put here.

Comment: The error references a log file. You can find more detailed information there. I noticed you use `python312-32` I think that's the 32 bit python and pandas may not work with it. You should be using the 64 bit version of python unless there is some uncommon reason why you have to use the 32 bit one. Step 1 for me would be to uninstall that python and install the 64 bit.

Comment: Also looking at PyPi, There's no support yet Python 3.12. https://pypi.org/project/pandas/

Comment: I have to use 3.12 because PythonNet 3.0.3 requires it.  I will try the 64 bit version and let you know how it works.

Comment: I am able to install Pandas when using the 64 bit version but Pythonnet is not working with the 64 bit version.  I have to have Pythonnet to use Python with VB.net and I have to have Pandas to run the Python functions that I need.  It seems that I am stuck between a rock and a hard place.